# why not save into folder magento 2

Tags: magento2, image

**Save in DB but not in folder**

```
if ((isset($_FILES['featured_image']['name'])) && ($_FILES['featured_image']['name'] != '') && (!isset($data['featured_image']['delete']))) {
            try {
                $uploaderFactory = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'featured_image']);
                $uploaderFactory->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
                $imageAdapter = $this->adapterFactory->create();
                $uploaderFactory->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                $uploaderFactory->setFilesDispersion(true);
                //$mediaDirectory = $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath();
                //$destinationPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('');
                $destinationPath = $this->_varDirectory->getAbsolutePath('importexport/');
                $media = $destinationPath . 'importexport/';
                $result = $uploaderFactory->save($destinationPath);

                if (!$result) {
                    throw new LocalizedException(
                        __('File cannot be saved to path: $1', $destinationPath)
                    );
                }

                $imagePath = 'importexport/' . $result['file'];

                $data['featured_image'] = $imagePath;
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__("Image not Upload Pleae Try Again"));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I forgot to add***

```
 enctype'=>'multipart/form-data


 $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
            ['data' => ['id' => 'edit_form', 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data','action' => $this->getData('action'), 'method' => 'post']]
        );
```